# Need excel formula to compile data without specific identifiers

Tags: excel

I'm usually pretty good at excel, but this one has me stumped. Basically, I have a table with different entities and their currency amounts. However, some entities have an additional row below them with additional amounts. This new row doesn't have any specific identifiers tied to the entity, so i can't just do a simple Index Match. I need to compile the data so that the table encompasses each entity's currency amounts with a single row. Examples of what I'm looking at are shown below.

**Original table**

[image]

**What I want it to be**

[image]

Comment: Easily done with Power Query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$3:$A$7=$I3)*($C$2:$E$2=J$2)*($C$3:$E$7+$C$4:$E$8*($A$4:$A$8="")))
```

[image]

**Explanation:**

So I will try to explain the formula for cell `J3` starting from the far end:

1. `$A$4:$A$8=""` - returns a bool array:

   ```
   {TRUE;
   FALSE;
   FALSE;
   TRUE;
   TRUE}
   ```
2. `$C$4:$E$8` - returns the array of values shifted one row down than the base array:

   ```
   {12000,0,0;
   70000,60000,45000;
   85,74,25;
   35,0,0;
   0,0,0}
   ```
3. Multiplying these two, `bool` values are converted to `True=1`, `False=0` and we obtain:

   ```
    {12000,0,0;
    0,0,0;
    0,0,0;
    35,0,0;
    0,0,0}
   ```
4. `$C$3:$E$7` - returns an array of values that can be called a base array:

   ```
   {5000,2000,10000;
   12000,0,0;
   70000,60000,45000;
   85,74,25;
   35,0,0}
   ```
5. Adding this to the result in point 3, we obtain:

   ```
   {17000,2000,10000;
   12000,0,0;
   70000,60000,45000;
   120,74,25;
   35,0,0}
   ```
6. `$C$2:$E$2=J$2` - returns an array of bool values:

   `{TRUE,FALSE,FALSE}`
7. Multiplying this by the result of point 5, we obtain:

   ```
   {17000,0,0;
   12000,0,0;
   70000,0,0;
   120,0,0;
   35,0,0}
   ```
8. `$A$3:$A$7=$I3` - returns an array of bool values

   ```
   {TRUE;
   FALSE;
   FALSE;
   FALSE;
   FALSE}
   ```
9. Multiply this by the result of point 7 to obtain:

   ```
   {17000,0,0;
   0,0,0;
   0,0,0;
   0,0,0;
   0,0,0}
   ```
10. `SUMPRODUCT` adds all the values of the array and we get the result - `17000`

Comment: this is exactly what I'm looking for!! If you don't mind, what type of SUMPRODUCT formula is this? i'd like to look into and understand each part. I've never seen it before. Specifically, what does the ($C$3:$E$7+$C$4:$E$8*($A$4:$A$8=""))) part say?

Answer (score 0):

You could add another column in your data (Entity2, column C below) and input a formula such as this in cell C3:

```
    =IF(ISBLANK(A3),A2,A3)
```

Then create a pivot on columns C:F.

[image]

If you don't want to use a pivot, then just copy your distinct Entities and use sumif formulas against columns C:F.